# Add string before URL in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I need to add the string `json-csv.com/?u=` before a URL such as `http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json` with NodeJS.

So far, I have:

```js
var urljoin = require('url-join');
var fullUrl = urljoin('json-csv.com/?u=', 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json');
console.log(fullUrl);
```

`urljoin` only seems to work if the string comes after the main URL. Can anyone provide some knowledge on how to add the string before so that, for example, it is possible to use `open(fullUrl);`?

Comment: Why not just use string concatenation?

Comment: ```let baseUrl = 'https://someurl.can.come.from.req; let fullUrl = `json-csv.com/?u=${baseUrl}```

Comment: @bilo-io, string concatenation won't work in this case either.

Comment: @Elnatanvazana, I'm receiving errors with your suggestion. Any chance you could elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

from the code snippet you shared it seems like it can be done with basic solution.
for example:

```
var baseUrl = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
var fullUrl = `json-csv.com/?u=${baseUrl}`

console.log(fullUrl) //===> json-csv.com/?u=http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json
```

let me know if this is the link you would like to have: `json-csv.com/?u=http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json`
the base URL you can get from the request if it should be dynamic.

---

this can be a solution for you

server

```
app.get('/somepath', ()=>{
 var baseUrl = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
 var fullUrl = `json-csv.com/?u=${baseUrl}`

 res.status(200).json({url: fullUrl})
})
```

client

```
fetch('/somepath')
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((res) => {
        window.open(
            res.url,
            '_blank'
        );
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, 'json-csv.com/?u=http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json' is the link I want to have. The first example certainly concatenates the two URLs into one. The problem is that it is not possible to open the combined URL, only the 'http://api...' part. The second example seems to be more in line with what I need. However, it is not possible to follow the produced link from the console here either, it looks like a static string when called.

Comment: how do you try to open it? are you returning to the front end?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It needs to redirect the user to the full URL so that a CSV file is downloaded (basically what the 'json-csv.com/?u=' does). I think I see a problem with the path example. When called, the console output has backslashes instead of common slashes.

Comment: this is what I get -- > json-csv.com\?u=\http:\api.open-notify.org\iss-now.json

Comment: i edited my answer you can check the last part of the answer

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at your suggestion. I'll come back to you if it checks out.